# Bootstrap Table Filterby , filter by date range showing nothing

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Currently using the Bootstrap Table library by wenzhixin. This one here
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table.
I've run into an issue with the the filterby option. I created the table through Echoing of PHP code rather than using a json to import the data.So in reality it still an HTML based table. The main issue i'm having is filtering rows by date range. I'm also using the moment.js scripts to compile an array of dates to use in the bootstrap table filterby.

Here is a JSfiddle Example of what i'm trying to achieve. As you will see when trying to pick a date to filter although the moment.js works the filterby will return nothing.

https://jsfiddle.net/rsnwvkz3/1/

```
$(function() 
{
$('#table').bootstrapTable()
}
)

//Moment.JS Return Date Ranges
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
var dateArray = [];
var currentDate = moment(startDate);
var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push( '"'+moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'"' )
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
}
return dateArray;
}


 $('#ok').click( function() 
 { 

var $table = $('#table')
var from=$("input[type=date][name=date1]" ).val();
var to=$("input[type=date][name=date2]" ).val();
  alert(getDates(from,to))
$table.bootstrapTable('filterBy',{ ETA:[getDates(from,to)]}) 



})
```

Answer (score 1):

The date array need to remove double quotation marks and filterBy param accept 
one-dimensional array.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
})

//Moment.JS Return Date Ranges
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = [];
    var currentDate = moment(startDate);
    var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dateArray;
}


$('#ok').click(function() {

    var $table = $('#table')
    var from = $("input[type=date][name=date1]").val();
    var to = $("input[type=date][name=date2]").val();
    alert(getDates(from, to))
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
        ETA: getDates(from, to)
    })



})
```